# A field or property with the name 'ActualService ' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

As I am adding some columns to gridview, I have got the above error. But ActualService is the same Column that I have in database. Please help me to resolve this Error.

My Code:

```
<Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PMRMName" SortExpression="PMRMName">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='<%# "db_PmuKpi_CF_AllPMs.aspx?PMRMID="+ Eval("PMRMID") + "&PMRMName =" + Eval("PMRMName")%>' Text='<%# Eval("PMRMName","{0}")%>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRM" runat="server"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      <asp:BoundField DataField="BudgetRevenue" HeaderText="BudgetRevenue" SortExpression="BudgetRevenue" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BudgetCOGS" HeaderText="BudgetCOGS" SortExpression="BudgetCOGS" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BudgetService" HeaderText="BudgetService" SortExpression="BudgetService" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="BudgetCashFlow" HeaderText="BudgetCashFlow" SortExpression="BudgetCashFlow" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualRevenue" HeaderText="ActualRevenue" SortExpression="ActualRevenue" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualCOGS" HeaderText="ActualCOGS" SortExpression="ActualCOGS" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualService " HeaderText="ActualService " SortExpression="ActualService " />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="ActualCashFlow " HeaderText="ActualCashFlow " SortExpression="ActualCashFlow " />
</Columns>
```

I use the follwing SQL:

```
select PMRMID,PMRMName,BudgetRevenue,BudgetCOGS,BudgetService,BudgetCashFlow, ActualRevenue, ActualCOGS, ActualService,ActualCashFlow from [fn_pmukpi_CurrentMonthCF_AllRMs] ---------my function –
```

Comment: Can you post your sql please?

Comment: iam taking it from my function.

Comment: select PMRMID,PMRMName,BudgetRevenue,BudgetCOGS,BudgetService,BudgetCashFlow, ActualRevenue, ActualCOGS, ActualService,ActualCashFlow from [fn_pmukpi_CurrentMonthCF_AllRMs] ---------my function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space after "ActualService " and "ActualCashFlow " in your column name of the BoundField (DataField).